# C++: Dealing with 'Vector subscript out of range'

Tags: c++, stdvector, openframeworks

Using openFrameworks 0.7.4, VS2012, v100 Platform Toolset.

I'm making a family of circles, each spawning children circles if `circles.size() < 200 && rand() % 20 == 0`.

Each circle is pushed into a `std::vector` using its `push_back()` function.

The lines of the polygon constructed by the children circles are drawn according to a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` where each of its elements contain 6 integer values, each being the previous child and current child circle's x and y positions, 
and the index of the previous and current child circle in the previously mentioned `std::vector`.

And at random times I get this error.

[image: error]

I tried using `cout` to check how many elements do the two vectors hold and the results were not constant:

```
1: circles.size() = 57, lines.size() = 56;
2: circles.size() = 42, lines.size() = 41;
3: circles.size() = 72, lines.size() = 71;
4: circles.size() = 78, lines.size() = 77;
```

The error mentioned pressing 'retry' to debug.

[image: auto watch]

The problem must be in `circles`.

These are the top parts and bottom parts when `circles` is collapsed.

[image: top]
[image: bottom]

I read some questions already asked on Stack Overflow but I don't think that my problem is on using `=` instead of `push_back()` or a 'stack corruption'.

The source codes:

**testApp.cpp**

```
#include "testApp.h"

void testApp::setup(){
ofSetWindowShape(1200, 800);
ofBackground(0, 0, 0);

lCircles = lLines = 0;

circle rc = circle(600, 400);
circles.push_back(rc);

ofEnableAlphaBlending();
}

void testApp::update(){
cout << circles.size() << ", " << lines.size() << endl;

if (circles.size() < 200) {
    if (rand() % 20 == 0) {
        int ci = rand() % circles.size();

        detectIndex(ci, true);

        if (!circles[ci].isNear) {
            circles[ci].isNear = true;

            int iterant = rand() % 7 + 3;
            int actual = 0;

            for (int cci = 0; cci < iterant; cci++) {
                circle nc = circle(circles[ci].x + cos(360 / iterant * cci * PI / 180) * spawnRadius, circles[ci].y + sin(360 / iterant * cci * PI / 180) * spawnRadius);
                if (!detectCircle(nc, true)) {
                    circles.push_back(nc);
                    actual++;
                    circles[ci].radius++;
                }
            }

            for (int sli = circles.size() - actual + 1; sli < circles.size(); sli++) {
                std::vector<int> nline;
                nline.push_back(circles[sli - 1].x);
                nline.push_back(circles[sli - 1].y);
                nline.push_back(circles[sli].x);
                nline.push_back(circles[sli].y);
                nline.push_back(sli - 1);
                nline.push_back(sli);
                lines.push_back(nline);
            }

            std::vector<int> nline;
            nline.push_back(circles[circles.size() - actual].x);
            nline.push_back(circles[circles.size() - actual].y);
            nline.push_back(circles[circles.size() - 1].x);
            nline.push_back(circles[circles.size() - 1].y);
            nline.push_back(circles.size() - actual);
            nline.push_back(circles.size() - 1);
            lines.push_back(nline);
        }
    }
}
}

bool testApp::detectIndex(int ci, bool change = false) {
bool res = false;

for (int chi = 0; chi < circles.size(); chi++) {
    if (ci != chi) {
        if (ofDist(circles[ci].x, circles[ci].y, circles[chi].x, circles[chi].y) < circles[ci].aradar * circles[ci].radius) {
            res = true;
            if (change) circles[ci].isNear = circles[chi].isNear = true;
        }
    }
}

return res;
}

bool testApp::detectCircle(circle ci, bool change = false) {
bool res = false;

for (int chi = 0; chi < circles.size(); chi++) {
    if (ofDist(ci.x, ci.y, circles[chi].x, circles[chi].y) < ci.aradar * ci.radius) {
        res = true;
        if (change) ci.isNear = circles[chi].isNear = true;
    }
}

return res;
}

void testApp::draw(){
for (int dci = 0; dci < circles.size(); dci++) {
    ofSetColor(circles[dci].color);
    ofCircle(circles[dci].x, circles[dci].y, circles[dci].radius);
    ofNoFill();
    ofSetColor(circles[dci].color, 128);
    ofCircle(circles[dci].x, circles[dci].y, circles[dci].aradar * circles[dci].radius);
    ofFill();
}

for (int dli = 0; dli < lines.size(); dli++) {
    ofSetColor(circles[lines[dli][4]].color);
    ofLine(lines[dli][0], lines[dli][1], (lines[dli][2] + lines[dli][0]) / 2, (lines[dli][3] + lines[dli][1]) / 2);
    ofSetColor(circles[lines[dli][5]].color);
    ofLine(lines[dli][2], lines[dli][3], (lines[dli][2] + lines[dli][0]) / 2, (lines[dli][3] + lines[dli][1]) / 2);
}
}

void testApp::keyPressed(int key){
    ofSaveFrame();
}
```

**non-default part of testApp.h**

```
#define spawnRadius 50

#include "circle.h"

class testApp : public ofBaseApp {
    public:
        ...
        std::vector<circle> circles;
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> lines;

        bool detectIndex(int ci, bool change);
        bool detectCircle(circle ci, bool change);

        int lCircles;
        int lLines;
```

**circle.h**

```
#include "ofMain.h"

class circle {

public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int radius;
    int aradar;

    ofColor color;

    bool isNear;

    circle(int cx, int cy) {
        x = cx;
        y = cy;
        radius = 5;
        aradar = 6;

        color = ofColor(ofRandom(255));

        isNear = false;
    }

};
```

I don't really know how to use the debugger in VS and I would really like some help with the code or with the debugger.

Comment: > I read some questions already asked on Stack Overflow but I don't think that my problem is on using = instead of push_back() or a 'stack corruption'.  What exactly are you doing??? Can you post that code?

Comment: Try using vector<T>::at() everywhere you subscript. That way you will get an instant crash when bounds are violated. This is easier to debug.

Comment: @MarcClaesen: good idea.  Or use valgrind or another bounds-checking tool to do similar without modifying the code.

Comment: Also you pasted the variable definitions, but there is a call stack there somewhere (tab I think) which will show you where you were in your code... click on your function name, it will show you the code and line it was trying to execute. The variable shown in auto/locals should then tell you what was going on

Comment: edit last comment - "going on" - read being accessed. look at loop variables and what the values are when they appear in between []